# Creating a dynamic navigation menu in php (indexing)

Tags: php, json

For my dynamic navigation I need some help, since I'm still new to PHP.
Using these functions, this file passes the values ​​of the array to a json and a js file.
The correct indexing is particularly important for the function.

```
$_js_remc->remote_copy($renaming_js_file, $renaming_js_file_to);
  $_json_remc->remote_copy($renaming_jsonfile, $renaming_jsonfile_to);

  if ($_js_remc->remote_is_writeable($renaming_js_file) && $_json_remc->remote_is_writeable($renaming_jsonfile)) {
        $i = 10000;
        $menu_string = "document.getElementById('categories_menu').innerHTML='";
        for ($z = 0; $z < count($_POST['menu_lvl1_text']); $z++) {

             $i = $i + 100;  
             $menu_string .= '<li><a href="' . $_POST['menu_lvl1_link'][$z] . '">' . htmlentities($_POST['menu_lvl1_text'][$z], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") . '</a>';
             $linkname_lvl1 = ($_POST['menu_lvl1_text'][$z]);
             $url_lvl1 = ($_POST['menu_lvl1_link'][$z]);
             $menu_list[$i] = array($linkname_lvl1 => $url_lvl1);

             if (isset($_POST['menu' . $z . '_lvl2_text']) && !empty($_POST['menu' . $z . '_lvl2_text'])) {
                    $i = $i +1;
                    $menu_string .= '<ul>';
                    for ($zs = 0; $zs < count($_POST['menu' . $z . '_lvl2_text']); $zs++) {
                    $menu_string .= '<li><a href="' . $_POST['menu' . $z . '_lvl2_link'][$zs] . '">' . htmlentities($_POST['menu' . $z . '_lvl2_text'][$zs], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") . '</a>';      
                    $linkname_lvl2 = ($_POST['menu' . $z . '_lvl2_text'][$zs]);
                    $url_lvl2 = ($_POST['menu' . $z . '_lvl2_link'][$zs]);
                    $menu_list[$i] = array($linkname_lvl2 => $url_lvl2);
                    $i = $i + 1;                        
                    }
                    $menu_string .= '</ul>';

             }
             $menu_string .= '</li>';
       }       
       $menu_string .= "';";
```

As you can see from the code, the json file logically logs the following values.

```
 {
    "10100": {
        "Lvl_1_1": "Level_1_1"
    },
    "10101": {
        "Lvl1_2": "Lvl1_2"
    },
    "10102": {
        "Lvl1_3": "Lvl1_3"
    },
    "10203": {
        "Lvl_2_1": "Lvl_2_1"
    },
    "10204": {
        "Lvl2_2": "Lvl2_2"
    }
}
```

Problem: 
The Sublevel (for ex. "10102") is, of course, to be incremented, but only within it's category, after which the index for the next category shell resume, for example, "10200". Each category has different numbers of sublinks.

The output will look like:

```
   <li id="u_1_0">
          <a href="#"><span id="i_1_0"></span></a>
          <ul class="sub">
            <li id="u_1_2"><a href="#"><span id="i_1_2"></span></a></li>
            <li id="u_1_3"><a href="#"><span id="i_1_3"></span></a></li>
```

Does someone know advice?

Comment: Please explain more what's your input array and what will be the output as navigation .

Comment: $menu_list is used for the input,

Answer (score 0):

If you struggle only with resetting your counter `$i`, you could just reset the counter after the inner for loop:

```
if ($_js_remc->remote_is_writeable($renaming_js_file) && $_json_remc->remote_is_writeable($renaming_jsonfile)) {
        $i = 10000;
        $menu_string = "document.getElementById('categories_menu').innerHTML='";
        for ($z = 0; $z < count($_POST['menu_lvl1_text']); $z++) {

             $i = $i + 100;  
             $menu_string .= '<li><a href="' . $_POST['menu_lvl1_link'][$z] . '">' . htmlentities($_POST['menu_lvl1_text'][$z], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") . '</a>';
             $linkname_lvl1 = ($_POST['menu_lvl1_text'][$z]);
             $url_lvl1 = ($_POST['menu_lvl1_link'][$z]);
             $menu_list[$i] = array($linkname_lvl1 => $url_lvl1);

             if (isset($_POST['menu' . $z . '_lvl2_text']) && !empty($_POST['menu' . $z . '_lvl2_text'])) {
                    $oldCounter = $i;
                    $menu_string .= '<ul>';
                    for ($zs = 0; $zs < count($_POST['menu' . $z . '_lvl2_text']); $zs++) {
                      $i = $i + 1;
                      [...use $i as before...]                                                
                    }
                    $i = $oldCounter;
                    $menu_string .= '</ul>';
             }
             $menu_string .= '</li>';
       }       
       $menu_string .= "';";
```

Notice that your ids are not unique. If there are 100 sublinks, you are in trouble!

However, I don't understand your second code block and how it is related to your question.